# SSH Into a server using NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to build an tool in nodeJS to make it easier to ssh into one of our acceptance or production servers. I just want to have the same result as if i type it into the terminal

```
exec("ssh <server-ip>", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
    return;
  }
  if (stderr) {
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Now i hoped this would ssh me into the server but it just shows an empty line

Comment: Not a solution, but how it connecting with nodejs better than with terminal?

Comment: we have a huge amount of servers. with different ip's trying to make a tool so its easier to navigate

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh

Comment: Node.JS is the wrong tool for this job. Why does it have to be Node? Simple Bash script should suffice easily.